# How could I generate a 2D array from a known slope and aspect value?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray, heightmap

Given a dummy heightmap (or digital elevation model) stored as a Numpy array like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

line = np.flip(np.arange(0, 10))
dem = np.tile(line, (10, 1))
```

I can calculate its slope and aspect like this:

```
x, y = np.gradient(dem)
slope = np.degrees(np.arctan(np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)))
aspect = np.degrees(np.arctan2(x, -y))
```

And visualise it:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
y, x = np.mgrid[:10, :10]
ax.scatter(x, y, dem)
ax.set_title(f"Slope={np.mean(slope)}, Aspect={np.mean(aspect)}")
```

[image]

But how would I go the other way?

I'd like to generate a blank 2D Numpy array of a fixed size, then fill it with values that follow a known slope and aspect (starting from an arbitrary elevation e.g. 0).

Comment: You literally just did it in the first line. What is your actual question?

Comment: Multiply the arange by the slope, add the offset

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: In other words, what did you try that you're actually having trouble with?

Comment: I want to go the other way! So with a known average slope and aspect, how would I combine them to form a heightmap?

Comment: So I won't know what dem is in advance, but I will have the shape of the array and the average slope and aspect. I would like to fill a blank array with height values that follow this slope and aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `gradient` assumes a step size of 1, the general formula for making a line with `N` points and a given `slope` and `offset` is

```
slope * np.arange(N) + offset
```

What you call Slope is the magnitude of the gradient, given as an angle. What you call Aspect is the ratio of partial slopes in the x- and y-directions, also given as an angle. You have the following system of non-linear equations:

```
np.tan(np.radians(slope))**2 = sx**2 + sy**2
np.tan(np.radians(aspect)) = -sx / sy
```

Luckily, you can solve this pretty easily using substitution:

```
p = np.tan(np.radians(slope))**2
q = np.tan(np.radians(aspect))
sy = np.sqrt(p / (q**2 + 1))
sx = -q * sy
```

Now all you need to do is take the outer sum of two lines with slopes `sx` and `sy`:

```
dem = offset + sx * np.arange(NX)[::-1, None] + sy * np.arange(NY)
```

Here is an example:

Inputs:

```
aspect = -30
slope = 45
offset = 1
NX = 12
NY = 15
```

Gradient:

```
p = np.tan(np.radians(slope))**2
q = np.tan(np.radians(aspect))
sy = np.sqrt(p / (q**2 + 1))   # np.sqrt(3) / 2
sx = -q * sy                   # 0.5
```

Result:

```
dem = offset + sx * np.arange(NX)[::-1, None] + sy * np.arange(NY)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
ax.scatter(*np.mgrid[:NX, :NY], dem)
```

[image]

Your conventions may be off by a sign, which you should be able to fix easily by looking at the plot.